# Can I toggle on/off the HUD display?

Tags: holdem-manager

I love the stats and all, but sometimes seeing so many numbers gives my brain cramps. Is there a way to toggle off the display and only toggle it on when I need it?

It's nice to have the clear plain Pokerstars view once in a while.

Comment: This is definitely possible in PokerTracker, so I'd be surprised if Holdem Manager didn't offer it. You could also customize the view to show a subset of stats that you thought were more useful to you. I think the HUD is one of the most useful features of these apps, so I can't really fathom why someone would want to remove it.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer For tournaments, all these stats sometimes blocks people stack sizes, so I would like to toggle it lol

Comment: Again, this is for PT and not HEM, but you can adjust the positions of the boxes to your liking and then save them so they become the defaults each time you restart the app. I had that problem also, but once I moved things around it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You could turn off the tracking program :p But seriously this is very easy to do right at the table with Pokertracker 4. You just click on the little PT4 icon at the top and then click "Disable HUD." I am not sure about HEM but I am sure that it is equally easy.